# All shaders render black while using shadergraph in unity 2020 1.10f

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

I am doing a simple animation in unity and I wanted to add portal efecct using shadergraph 8.2.0 and everything renders black [image]

like this

[image]

shader setings

I have no clue whatsoever what it is

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning the pipeline, however, I would think you need to scale up the texture on the top left, I can't read its name from the image. But you are getting the red/yellow mix, getting the swirl, but the area that's being blacked out is comparable to the texture I mentioned. Sorry I don't know how to put it exactly, but the white to grey to black gradient is not large enough so you are rendering the center fine just need to expand the white-grey area, I think scaling the texture up would produce the effect you want.